# Writing an App for OS X that allows users to select app with Contextual Menu item "Open With"

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, file-association, open-with

I have a Multimedia App that is for Mac OS X using Xcode.

The languages used are Objective-C, C++ and C.

I want to somehow get my app in the "Open With" contextual menu without having the user do anything. I don't want to "take over" the default association unless the user sets it in the Preferences or takes additional steps.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an entry for the document type you'd like to support to your application's `Info.plist` it should show up in that menu.  The easiest way to do this is to select your target and add the type in the `Info` tab.